# Как браузер сам применяет курсивный шрифт?

Tags: css

Всем доброго дня. В таблице стилей для загрузки веб шрифта использую правило

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Kurale';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src:url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/kurale/v2/qUcQKP0WQHGvJJtuLvvwEg.woff2) format('woff2'); 
}
```

Далее успешно применяю к абзацу p.

```
p {
  font-family: "Kurale";
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Но если указать в правиле p{font-style: italic;} то шрифт благополучно превращается в kurale КУРСИВНЫЙ. Вопроса собственно два:

1) Курсивный шрифт хранится в этом подгружаемом файле либо браузер такой умный, что трансформирует его из normal (сам прорисовывает). Т.Е. Откуда он знает как отобразить курсив этого шрифта;

2) Если курсивный шрифт в файле, то на правило @font-face {font-style: normal;} ему(браузеру) все равно и он руководствуется только названием шрифта?

P.S. информацией о содержании/несодержании в файле курсивного шрифта не владею.

Comment: Браузер mozila/ chrome последние

Comment: Если шрифт есть в файле, как обычно и бывает, то он оспользует его. Если нет, то сам имитирует курсив. Поэтому иногда курсив по разному выглядит на разных системах и браузерах.

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/css/font-style здесь в описании написано, но конкретного алгоритма конечно нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В свойстве `font-style` есть 3 возможных атрибута: `normal`, `italic`, и `oblique`.

`italic` - это курсивное начертание шрифта (не во всех шрифтах оно имеется).

`oblique` - это наклонное начертание шрифта (часто просто наклоненный шрифт).

Если браузер задать начертание `italic` или `oblique`, он выберет указанное начертание. А если начертания `italic` нет, то браузер выберет начертание `oblique`, если оно есть (кстати, и наоборот так же). А если никаких начертаний нет, то браузер самостоятельно сымитирует эффект наклоненного шрифта.

Чтобы контролировать поведение браузера в таких случаях, используется свойство `font-synthesis` (https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/font-synthesis)

Answer (score 2):

Если отображается курсивный Kurale, то да, файл содержит курсивное начертание. Так же можно еще попробовать менять [font-weight](http://htmlbook.ru/css/font-weight) и посмотреть вероятные начертания также присутствующие в файле.

Comment: Но я так понимаю, что возможна и ситуация когда шрифта нет и браузер сам отрисовывает курсив(согласно предыдущему комментарию?)

Comment: @VadimSlepakurov, всё верно, если курсива в файле шрифта нет, то браузер постарается его сам "додумать"

Comment: В Kurale нет курсивного начертания.

Comment: @labris https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Kurale все виды начертаний, если не была выбрана некоторая кастомная сборка woff шрифта. Ссылка ведет на google static, поэтому скорее всего начертание таки присутствует

Comment: В гугл фонтс для Kurale доступно только начертание Regular, если найдете другое - сообщите.

Comment: @labris каюсь, не обратил внимания, что выбор напротив Open Sans